# Access to 'Set-Cookies' header in $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers, session-cookies

I am new in AngularJS and stacked in simple place.

I run simple code:

```
$http.post('/api/login/', {"user":"alexey","password":"alexey"})
     .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
         console.log(headers());
     } );
```

And as a result in console just:

> Object {content-type: "application/json"}

But actual header contains a lot of other values (it's from Chrome network inspector):

```
HTTP/1.0 202 ACCEPTED
Date: Sun, 12 Oct 2014 17:39:33 GMT 
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5
Vary: Accept, Cookie 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json 
Allow: POST, OPTIONS 
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=rNzbxI3QXBoyBS9XaMCdVHmZ32k8VN3c; expires=Sun, 11-Oct-2015 17:39:33 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/ 
Set-Cookie: sessionid=jxwsm9b5wuelpnr3a00tuwonq0i9sksk; expires=Sun, 26-Oct-2014 17:39:33 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
```

So, how can i read another headers, exactly cookies from response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For security reasons, you can't access the `Set-Cookie` header on the response from XMLHttpRequest.  AngularJS `$http` uses the browsers XMLHttpRequest implementation.

[4.7.4 The getAllResponseHeaders() method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getresponseheader()-method)

> Returns all headers from the response, with the exception of those
>   whose field name is Set-Cookie or Set-Cookie2.

Comment: There it is. I think why when I am trying to do `response.headers('Content-Type')`, I get the value. But response.headers('Set-Cookie') returns null or undefined. Is there an angular 1.6 work around to fetch the cookies. I mainly want to capture JSESSIONID.