# httpClient Type '"response"' is not assignable to type '"body"'

Tags: angular, httpclient

i am using httpClient:

```
get(url: string, options?:HttpOptionsInterface): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {

    return this.http.get(url, options).map((res: any) => {
        return res;
    }).catch((error: any) => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
            this.error401Handler();
        }
        return Observable.throw(error);
    });
}
```

and this is my HttpOptionsInterface:

```
export interface HttpOptionsInterface {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: 'response';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}
```

but i got error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'HttpOptionsInterface' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header:
>   string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
>   Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
>       Type '"response"' is not assignable to type '"body"'.

sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-options).

Comment: Hi, The HTTPClient GET request options are optional, so you do not have to specify this unless you want to send parameters. Otherwise you can just put the URL of the API.

Comment: You have made your Interface with `observe` as optional, in that case it will consider it as `body` by default, if you want to have it as `response` make it compulsory

Comment: @xyz thank you, i actually needed this.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like "observe" should be "body" and not "response" in your interface definition.

Comment: i'm using 'response' because i want to return the full response.

Comment: @FatemeFazli then try setting "any" instead of "response" (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47761516/1182487)