# how to add the header token that I have in my localstorage in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have these methods in my auth.service and an auth.interceptor.ts code in order to take the token from header and I want to send it with post method what should add in header in order to set the token? Any help is much appreciated!!

```
 //shop.service.ts

const httpOptions = {

headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
'Authorization': 'X-OBSERVATORY-AUTH'}) 

};

addShop (shop: Shop): Observable<Shop> {

return this.http.post<Shop>(this.shopsUrl, shop, httpOptions);
}


// auth.interceptor.ts

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

  const authToken = this.authService.getToken();

  const authRequest = req.clone({

    headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken)

  });

  return next.handle(authRequest);
}



//auth.service.ts

getToken() {
return this.token;
}


login( username: string,  password: string) {

var user: User = {  username: username, password: password };
this.http 
  .post<any>("http://localhost:3000/observatory/api/login",user, 
   {observe:'response'})
  .subscribe((res) => {
    const token = res.headers.get('X-OBSERVATORY-AUTH');
    console.log(token);
    this.token = token;

    if (token!==null) {

      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.userId = res.body._id;
      this.isAdmin=res.body.isAdmin;
      this.userAdmin=res.body.isAdmin;
      this.username=res.body.username;
      this.authStatusListener.next(true);
      this.saveAuthData(token, this.userId,this.username, this.isAdmin);
```

}
      });

Comment: You can make use of interceptor, someone already wrote an article for that

[Medium link](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

Comment: I have this interceptor..how can I use it? wait please to add the code I have in the question form

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. `shop.service.ts` should add headers just fine. Do the same in `auth.service.ts`:

```
this.http.post<any>(url, user, { 
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      'Authorization': 'X-OBSERVATORY-AUTH'
    }), 
    observe: 'response'
  });
```

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers

To add headers on ALL (or almost all) HTTP requests, use a HTTP Interceptor (see @Chenna 's comment)

## Edit:

Apologies for posting untested code. See [Angular 4/5 HttpClient: Argument of type string is not assignable to 'body'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761262/angular-4-5-httpclient-argument-of-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-body) for why the previous version produced an error. In short, you need to either inline the `observe` or use a few ugly tricks.

### OR: use a HTTP Interceptor. End of all your worries.

Comment: I copied it in my code and the console returned an error:

Comment: Error:Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; observe: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
  Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"body"'.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the interceptor created. You just need to provide it in the module so it can intercept the requests.

```
providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: YourInterceptorClass, multi: true }]
```