# Why i got an Angular error on this HttpHeader?

Tags: angular, typescript

can somebody help mewhy i got an error in my Angular code when i want to use HttpHeaders to read response status from backend? This is the clear error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQu5t.jpg

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CrudService {

  // Base api url
  public url = 'http://localhost:8080/';
  headerProperty: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createUser(data) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'todo', data);
  }

  createAddress(data) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'address', data);
  }

  loginstudent(data) {
    const postHttpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
   }),
  observe: 'response' as 'body'
 };

  return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/' + 'login', data, 
postHttpOptions)
  .pipe(map(response => {
         return response;
    }));

  }
}
```

I already edit the code and add as 'body' into my code but now i have a new problem with my component

```
saveStudentDetails(values) {
  const studentData = new FormData();

  studentData.append('id', values.id);
  studentData.append('password', values.password);
  this.crudService.loginstudent(studentData).subscribe(result => {
    if (result.headers.status === '202') {
      this.router.navigate(['address']);
      alert('"success"');
      return;
    }
  });
}
```

It says property 'headers' does not exist on type 'object'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4/5 HttpClient: Argument of type string is not assignable to 'body'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761262/angular-4-5-httpclient-argument-of-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-body)

Comment: i already my code but have a new problem

Comment: @HisyamSyazani try putting result: any => ... in your saveStudentDetails method

Comment: Remove observe altogether.

Comment: @NemanjaG What do you mean? Where should i put it? in my if statement?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz still got error but its said property 'headers' does not exist in type 'object'

Comment: @HisyamSyazani this.crudService.loginstudent(studentData).subscribe(result: any => {...}

Comment: @NemanjaG if i put the :any it says that it canot fint the name result

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because `result` is of type `{}` which doesn't have any properties. You need to give it a type doing either of the following:

```
this.http.post<any>(...)
```

Or

```
(result: any)
```

But `any` shouldn't be used since it is poor TypeScript. Instead specify what your response looks like in a custom interface, for example:

```
export interface ICustomResponse {
  data: any;
  error: string;
}
```

And then use it like:

```
this.http.post<ICustomResponse>(...)
```

Or

```
(result: ICustomResponse)
```

Comment: i already make the interface but in my login component saveStudentDetails() on the if else statement it says the headers does not exists in the interface