# How can i retrieve a status code in Angular?

Tags: angular, httpresponse

I am new to Angular and for practice i want to make a small application where a user can log in just with his username at first. In order to do so i would like to store the logged in user if the backend returns http status 200. But i can't get the http status of my request. I already looked up several posts here and on other sites, but all those solutions don't seem to work for me.

My Angular Version is: 8.2.14

Here is my login service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../model/User';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  loginUrl = 'login';
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }),
  };

  login(user: User) {
    const request = this.http
      .post(this.loginUrl, user, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    return request;
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log('handleError Method');
    console.log('Errorcode', error.status);
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`
      );
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

And this is the Login Component calling the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LoginService } from 'src/app/services/login.service';
import { User } from '../../../model/User';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-component',
  templateUrl: './login-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-component.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;
  user: User;
  // loginService: LoginService;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    const dummyUser = { username, password };
    this.loginService.login(dummyUser).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('data', data);
      this.user = data;
      console.log('user', this.user);
    });
  }
}
```

**Edit**:

With the answer of Mari Mbiru and this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/47761516/12360845 i was able to solve this question. I actually tried to set `observe:'response'` before but i didn't put it into `httpOptions` but in `HttpHeaders` which didn't work.
My working post request looks like this now:

```
login(user: User) {
    const request = this.http
      .post<User>(
        `${this.loginUrl}`,
        { username: user.username, password: user.password },
        {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
          observe: 'response',
        }
      )
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    return request;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can get HttpClient Status Code in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639154/how-can-get-httpclient-status-code-in-angular-4)

Comment: Please always try to minify your example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpClient allows you to view the full response instead of just the body by adding `{observe: 'response'}` to your request options. This will return a HttpResponse object that has the body, headers, status, url etc.

So the httpOptions should be:

```
 httpOptions = {
 observe:'response'
 headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 }),
};
```

And in the subscription :

```
this.loginService.login(dummyUser).subscribe((res) => {
       console.log('response', res);
       this.user = res.body;
       console.log('user', this.user);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't convert the response to JSON then you can find it here

HTTP.post(’.....’).subscribe( (res) => res[’status’], (err) =>.....);