# Not able to read authorization header in response of spring boot in angular 5 application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, spring-rest

I am getting my hands dirty by building an application using the spring framework and Angular 5.

I have the backend of the application ready using spring boot, spring rest and spring security. For the purpose of this application, I have used spring JWT tokens for the purpose of authorization.

I have tested the backend services using postman and they are working fine without any glitch.

Now when I try to integrate the application to the front end (Angular 5), I have been facing CORS issue as well as I am unable to access the response headers in in the service calls happening from the front end angular application.

I have already set CORS to Expose headers in response in WebSecurity file.

I am able to see in the response a token carrying the Authorization token in Chrome, but still unable to access.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Can anyone suggest what should be the right way to set the CORS in the spring boot application. My current application looks as below.

**User.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**UserController.java**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.model.User;
import com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.repository.UserRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository,
                          BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {

        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @PostMapping("/sign-up")
    public void signUp(@RequestBody User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.model.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl.java**

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.model.User;
import com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;


@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), emptyList());
    }

}
```

**WebSecurity.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;

import static com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.security.SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL;

import java.util.Arrays;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .and().cors().and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-type","Authorization"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

}
```

**JWTAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;

import com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.model.User;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import static com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.security.SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME;
import static com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.security.SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING;
import static com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.security.SecurityConstants.SECRET;
import static com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.security.SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            User creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), User.class);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
                .compact();
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }

}
```

**JWTAuthorizationFilter.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;

import static com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.security.SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME;
import static com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.security.SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING;
import static com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.security.SecurityConstants.SECRET;
import static com.app.mycompany.TasksApp.security.SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX;

public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();
            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Angular UI Service call**

I have changed the api to use the HttpClient method as well and observe the response. Still I am unable to access the headers in response.

```
authenticate(credentials, callback) {

    const AuthorizationHeader = credentials ? 'Basic ' + btoa(credentials.username + ':' + credentials.password) : '';

    const serviceheaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization' : AuthorizationHeader});

    // const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    //   'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization' : AuthorizationHeader
    // });

    const username = credentials ? credentials.username : '';
    const password = credentials ? credentials.password : '';

    this.http.post<HttpResponse<any>>('http://localhost:8080/login', JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})
          , {headers: serviceheaders, observe: 'response', responseType: 'json'})
                  .subscribe( (response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
                    console.log('Headers only: ' + response.headers);
                    console.log('Response Headers : ' + response.headers.get('Authorization'));
                    const token = response.headers.get('Authorization');
                    if (token !== null) {
                      this.authenticated = true;
                    }
                    return callback && callback();
    });

  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505619/angular-4-3-3-httpclient-how-get-value-from-the-header-of-a-response

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for your response. However in this case, I believe the issue is more because of the cors security that is not allowing me to access the headers. I have set the "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"  in the backend service. However, I am still not able to access the Authorization key in the response headers. Can you let me know If the way I have set the cors configuration on my backend is proper.

Comment: Not too familiar with backend stuff ;) But at least if you do not `observe` the response, there is no way to access the headers.

Comment: Hi Alex, Sorry about not having informed. I have done those modifications as well in the service call from the front end to observe the response. Please find the updated method - authenticate() where I have explicitly added the variable to observe the response in the http call. Can you confirm if that is the right way to use it? with this modification as well, when i try to get response.headers.get('Authorization), i see a null being printed on the console

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late but I had a similar problem with React + Spring Boot. It was solved by adding "config.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"))" in my CORS configuration:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config.applyPermitDefaultValues());
    config.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));

    return source;
}
```

In my frontend I did the following:

```
export default function ({ history }) {
   const [login, setLogin] = useState('');
   const [password, setpassword] = useState('');

   async function handleLogin(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       const response = await Api.post('/login', {
           login, senha: password
       });

       console.log(response.headers);
       if(response.headers['authorization']){
           history.push("/menu");
       }
}
```

As you can see, the "Authorization" header comes in lower case.