# Can't access property from POST response headers in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, header, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm trying to access CSRF Token received from POST response header, which I need to send back with every further request from my app. I'm was able to drill down the response stream until I could access the [[Entries]] which has the "csrfpreventionsalt" token. It gets displayed in console but when trying to access it shows as undefined.

**Tried & Tested:**
I've tried the "get" method to access the header but it didn't work.

var csrf = res.headers.get('csrfpreventionsalt');

I've seen other questions on SO which say that you can't access the header value but If I can access the header in console then definately I should be able to access the token & assign it to a variable.

Solution to this might help others as well who could face the same situation in their apps. Any help is welcome !!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the get method after calling the json() method, basically I could get the csrf value after accessing it in the raw response object like below:

```
private extractLoginData = (res: Response) => {
    this.csrfToken = res.headers.get('csrfPreventionSalt');
    let body = res.json();
    return body;
}
```

Also make sure that you have your service has set the header fields as "*" for Access-Control-Allow-Headers & Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Also add your "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true".

Answer (score 0):

you need to map your response to get method like

```
this.http.get('…', { observe: 'response' });
```

as per new httpclient in angular,  if you're still interested in the whole Response object you can observe for it

please check [here](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

```html
Map.forEach((value: boolean, key: string) => {
    console.log(key, value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question has already been asked on SO check this out

[Angular 4.3.3 HttpClient : How get value from the header of a response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505619/angular-4-3-3-httpclient-how-get-value-from-the-header-of-a-response/45506099)

I would have just put this in a comment but I don't have enough clout to comment just yet sorry