# how to access http response header in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, http

Angular -cli 6 using HttpClient and HttpHeaders.

My code is as follows:

```
public getData(params: any): Observable<any> {
   let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer xxx'});
   httpHeaders.append('x-auth-token', '');

   return this.http.get('host', {headers: httpHeaders})
   .pipe(
      map(response => {
         return response;
      })
   );
}
```

How do I access the X-Auth-Token from a response header?
In the developer tool, I see

```
X-Auth-Token: 23e0bef4-8c77-4554-ad1a-1ec4ae134f86
```

I did see the mentioned possible duplicate question but making the proposed changes

```
'observe': 'response',
            'x-auth-token': ''
```

I still fail to see the response headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4.3.3 HttpClient : How get value from the header of a response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505619/angular-4-3-3-httpclient-how-get-value-from-the-header-of-a-response)

Comment: I did implement the proposed changes to no avail

Comment: Have you exposed the X-Auth-Token by putting it in Access-Control-Expose-Headers in server?Not all headers can be accessed in javascript.

Comment: yes and that did work, thank you