# Access HttpClient post response headers

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post, httpclient

I am trying to access the headers in the response of a HttpClient post request (also Put request), but it shows undefined. It works perfectly with a get response though.

httpClient.post("url", {observe:"response"}). subscribe(response => {
 console.log(response.headers);  // undefined

console.log(response.headers.get("header-name")); // error
});

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Are you following the guidance in [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#45505619](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505619/angular-4-3-3-httpclient-how-get-value-from-the-header-of-a-response)

Comment: I am not trying to send headers but use one I received from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
httpClient.post("url", {observe:"response"}).
pipe(map(response => { 
console.log(response.headers.get('nameofheader'))
}));
```

Comment: I still get undefined

Comment: what version of angular you use ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works.

httpClient.request("POST", "url", {observe:"response"}). subscribe(response => { 
console.log(response.headers.get("header-name")); // OK
});