# Get the full http response in case of an error

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs

In angular documentation they stated that you have to specify `observe: "response"` on the provided options to get the full http response, which I did here:

```
constructor(private service: new () => T,
  private http: HttpClient,
  private httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandlerService,
){ 
    this._handleError = this.httpErrorHandler.createHandleError(this.service.name);
}
private _handleError: HandleError;
//...other code
delete(resourceNameOrId: number | string): Observable<HttpErrorResponse>{
    return this.http.delete<T>(this._url + resourceNameOrId, {
      observe: "response"
    }).pipe(
      catchError(this._handleError(`delete`, null))
    );
  }
```

The handleError function is defined in this service:

```
export type HandleError = <T> (operation?: string, result?: T) => (error: HttpErrorResponse) => Observable<T>;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpErrorHandlerService {

  constructor(private errorService: ErrorService, private modalService: NzModalService) { }

  createHandleError = (serviceName = '') => <T> (operation = 'operation', result = {} as T) => this.handleError(serviceName, operation, result);

  handleError<T> (serviceName = '', operation = 'operation', result = {} as T ){
    return (error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<T> => {
      const message = (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) ? error.error.message: `{error code: ${error.status}, body: "${error.message}"}`;
      this.errorService.errorMessage = `${serviceName} -> ${operation} failed.\n Message: ${message}`;
      console.error(this.errorService.errorMessage);
      return of(result);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is an example of how I call my service delete function in a component:

```
this.service.delete(nom).subscribe(data => {
  if(!this.errorService.errorMessage){
    this.notificationService.success("Suppression", "L'enregistrement a été supprimée !");
  }
});
```

But specifying the `observe: "response"` didn't work in my case, and the `error: HttpErrorResponse` only returns the error message and not the full response :

[image]

I have tried solutions in this thread : [Angular 4.3.3 HttpClient : How get value from the header of a response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505619/angular-4-3-3-httpclient-how-get-value-from-the-header-of-a-response) which didn't work for me, and the provided solution was to define the observe option.

How can I solve this ?

## Update:

The the observe option only works when the delete http request returns a 200 code as shown in screenshot below, but when there is a 404 response status the response object in this case is null, and in the handleError function the response body is the only thing I can access to.

[image]

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem in a stackblitz but I get the full error response as the HttpErrorResponse, as it should be: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hh4x4z I'm not really sure what your problem is. Please provide a stackblitz yourself that showcases your error and the problem you have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it fit to you to intercept the HttpClient hook via Interceptor? 
Try something Like this:
Create an Interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class FinalInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private errorHandlerService: HttpErrorHandlerService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      return next.handle(req).pipe(
        tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof  HttpErrorResponse) {
              this.errorHandlerService.handleError(event);
            }
        }));
  }
}
```

AppModule:

```
providers: [
    ...
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: FinalInterceptor, multi: true },
  ],
```

so in my handler service on http errors i've got 
[next console.log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adqRc.png)

i suppose this is exactly what you looking for

Comment: Thanks, actually the problem was that in the application someone created an intercepter that catchs the error and only sends the message xD !

Comment: Hah x) at least it was useful

Answer (score 0):

If you want the HttpErrorResponse object inside your catchError, try to get it inside the block after the api call is completed, something like this:

```
delete(resourceNameOrId: number | string): Observable<HttpErrorResponse>{
    return this.http.delete<T>(this._url + resourceNameOrId)
 .pipe(
      catchError((error:any)=>{
           console.log(error);//error is the HttpErrorResponse object returned
           return this._handleError(`delete`, null)
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Actually this code will generate the following error : `[ts]
Argument of type '(error: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<HttpResponse<T>>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.`

Comment: Can you try returning an ErrorObservable inside your handleError method? 
    return ErrorObservable.create(result);

Comment: Do you mean `return throwError(result)` ? because in Angular 6 there is no `ErrorObservable`

Comment: Yeah. Try that.