# Response status code getting null Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I implemented post method in angular 7. I want status code of post request.

I did following.

```
const sub = this.service.regEvent(this.pId, this.email)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('response:', response);
        if(response.httpStatusCode === 200) {
        }
});

this.subscriptions.push(sub);
```

regEvent method

```
public regEvent(pId, email): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`this.endpointUrl?eventId=${pId}&email=${email}`,"").pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Here `console.log('response:', response);` **I am getting null.**

**In browser i checked and it's.**

[image]

**In postman also.**

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear why you *expected* `httpStatusCode` to be there. That's not what the property is called even if you *do* read the full response [as the docs tell you](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response). If you used a better type than `any` to describe the actual response, the compiler could help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [observe response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45506099/5621827) something like

```
this.http.post<any>(`this.endpointUrl?eventId=${pId}&email=${email}`,"",{observe: 'response'})
```