# get header parameter from http response in ionic 5.4.16

Tags: angular, http, http-headers, http-post, ionic5

I have a login service in odoo, which gives token in header response of login request. The subsequent requests require that token in headers only after that it will be authorized.

How can i access that token so that after saving it can be sent in next requests ?

Below is my tried code which doesn't work.

```
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
headers.append('');

this.testResp = this.httpClient.post(this.serverURL,this.postParam,{ headers: headers })
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data['_body']);
   }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Below is the postman request which gives me token in response header `session-id` in `Set-Cookie`.

[image: Postman Request]

> **Followed solution mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505619/angular-4-3-3-httpclient-how-get-value-from-the-header-of-a-response) but still it does not giving the expected result.**

Here is updated code

```
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
const options = {
      headers: headers,
      observe: "response" as 'body', // to display the full response & as 'body' for type cast
      responseType: "json"
    };

    this.testResp = this.httpClient.post(this.serverURL, this.postParam,  {headers: headers, observe: "response"})
    .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response.headers.has("Set-Cookie"));
        return response;
    }, err => {
        throw err;
    });
```