# HttpResponse "TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined"

Tags: angular

I need to access "status", "message" and so on from http response. In the "network" tab of chrome browser I do see everything that I need. But in the "subscribe" method the error that is returned doesn't define those attributes.

```
deleteBranchByID(branchID: string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + 'api/Branch/DeleteBranchByID/' + branchID);
  }
```

"Error" doesn't contain the attributes that I need...

```
onDelete(branchID) {
    this.branchesService.deleteBranchByID(branchID)
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {
          console.log(res);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }
```

...instead, console.log(error) returns this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (common-auth.js:945)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:29)
    at CatchSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:7)
    at InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:14)
    at InnerSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at Observable._Observable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Observable.scheduler.schedule.error.error [as _subscribe] (throwError.js:4)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at subscribeTo.js:20
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:7)
```

These same methods work perfectly in another project but not here.

Answer (score 0):

Add `observe: 'response'` object to get access to `status` from the response.

```
deleteBranchByID(branchID: string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + 'api/Branch/DeleteBranchByID/' + branchID, { observe: 'response' });
  }
```

I think you could be getting a `200` status code but the response is empty and therefore the http call fails but this is just a guess.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505619/angular-4-3-3-httpclient-how-get-value-from-the-header-of-a-response) out to see how to get headers, status codes, etc. from the response and not just the body.