# Angular http post with HttpResponse

Tags: angular

In my angular service (EmployeeService) I have the following:

```
  httpPostOption: { headers: any; observe: any; }  = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    }),
    observe: 'response'
  };
  
  createEmployeeWithHeaders(employee: IEmployee): Observable<HttpEvent<IEmployee>> {
    return this.http
      .post<IEmployee>(
        this.apiURL + '/employee',
        JSON.stringify(employee),
        this.httpPostOption 
      )
      .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

The problem is with the response (of type HttpEvent) - the code in the calling component is like this:

```
let post = {'firstName': this.currentFirstName(), 
            'lastName': this.currentLastName(), 
            'email': this.currentEmail(), 
            'phone': this.currentPhone(),
            'password': this.currentPassword()} as IEmployee
this.employeeService.createEmployeeWithHeaders(post).subscribe((response: HttpEvent<IEmployee>) => {
  console.log('Employee created', response)
```

The console.log shows both data and headers from the server but I´m unable to access **response.ok** or **response.statusText** like I can with a HttpResponse which I can get from a http.get-call to the server.

I´ve tried to change the method to this:

```
  createEmployeeWithHeaders(employee: IEmployee): Observable<HttpResponse<IEmployee>> {
    return this.http
      .post<IEmployee>(
        this.apiURL + '/employee',
        JSON.stringify(employee),
        this.httpPostOption 
      )
      .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

But changing the Observable to HttpReponse instead of HttpEvent cause an error like:

**Type 'HttpSentEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'HttpResponse': body, clone, headers, status, and 3 more**

Any suggestions on how to get the entire response as a HttpReponse?

Regards
Kaare

Comment: Have you tried this yet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505619/angular-4-3-3-httpclient-how-get-value-from-the-header-of-a-response

Answer (score 0):

If I replace:
**this.httpPostOption**
in

```
  createEmployeeWithHeaders(employee: IEmployee): Observable<HttpEvent<IEmployee>> {
    return this.http
      .post<IEmployee>(
        this.apiURL + '/employee',
        JSON.stringify(employee),
        this.httpPostOption 
      )
      .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

with: **{headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':  'application/json'}),observe: 'response'}** in

```
createCustomer(customer: ICustomer): Observable<HttpResponse<ICustomer>> {
    return this.http
      .post<ICustomer>(
        this.apiURL + '/customer/',
        JSON.stringify(customer),
        {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':  'application/json'}),observe: 'response'}
      ).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

It works - though I cannot see what the difference is